# Dimension of the Representation of the Suzuki and Ree Groups?

Tags: curves

What are the dimension of the group representation of $^2B_2$ and $^2G_2$? All what I know is that the first is 4 and the second group has two representation of dimension 7 and 13. Are there any?

Comment: When you ask, "Are there any?", what sort of object do you want?

Comment: Are there any other dimensions (i.e., spaces of different dimension where the group act?)